# Typeahead.js examples Autocomplete not working

Tags: node.js, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Tried to test the twitter's typeahead.js examples in jsfiddle.

Couldnt get it working though? Can you please help what I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: can you please elaborate what error you're getting when implementing autocomplete? a jsfiddle with your code would be very helpful to track down the problem.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jLa7x28y/6/

Comment: Added the jsfiddle link above. I tried using the typeahead examples I found online from twitter. Couldnt get that to work.

Comment: looks like you've edited your question and now it's completely a different problem.

Comment: Yes Aminur. I wanted to give more specific details as you had also recommended. And you know, I tried once again to debug the problem and I was able to get it working. I had the js added at the top earlier. Now I moved it to the end. It worked. :)

Comment: did you check my answer?

Comment: Ok yeah. I just saw that too. Thank you. Does it make a difference where do we keep the script tag though? I see you have added that js file under external resources. How does jsfiddle know where its to be used?

Comment: in jsfiddle you've to add external js/css files in external resources. those resources then added in the html header.

Comment: ok thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've update the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aminur/jLa7x28y/7/) you've attached in the comment. now it's working. you forgot to include jquery library and typehead script source `<script src="/js/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>` was not correct.